# How to call the methods of the model in django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have the model of Invoicetracker in Models.py and I want to call the methods of the model in the template.

```
Model.py
class  Invoicetracker(models.Model):
      TotalBillAmount = 0
      invoicenumber = models.IntegerField()
      invoicedate = models.DateTimeField()
      BillAmount = models.IntegerField()
      TotalPaid = models.IntegerField()
      Remark = models.CharField(max_length=100)

      def __str__(self):       
         return self.invoicenumber      

      def totalbill(self):
         total = Invoicetracker.objects.all().aggregate( TotalBillAmount = Sum('BillAmount'))
         return total

      def totalpaid(self):
         total = Invoicetracker.objects.all().aggregate(TotalPaid = Sum('TotalPaid'))
         return total
```

views.py

```
def invoicemgt(request):
    invoiceitem = Invoicetracker.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'order.html',{'invoiceitem' : invoiceitem})
```

I want to call the method totalbill and totalpaid in the order.html template. Can I call this through instance method? or Shall we use an classmethod?

Comment: post your views.py file too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call these in a [*variable*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#variables). So if you passed an `Invoicetracker` object to a template with the name `invoicetracker`, you can render this with:

```
{{ invoicetracker.totalbill }}
```

Note that you can not use brackets here. If the item is a callable, the template will automatically call it *without* parameters. Methods that thus *have* parameters, can not be called, or at least not without some extra "tricks".

That being said, here your method does *not* depend on the `self`. So that makes it more fit for a `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`. For example:

```
class  Invoicetracker(models.Model):
      # …

      @classmethod
      def totalbill(cls):
         return cls.objects.aggregate(TotalBillAmount=Sum('BillAmount'))['TotalPaid']

      @classmethod
      def totalpaid(cls):
         return cls.objects.aggregate(TotalPaid=Sum('TotalPaid'))['TotalPaid']
```

Then you can call these methods in your view, and pass the result to the template:

```
def some_view(request):
    total_paid = Invoicetracker.totalbill()
    total_bill = Invoicetracker.totalbill()
    return render(request, 'order.html', {'total_paid': total_paid, 'total_bill': total_bill})
```

Comment: I can get the answer by just call {{ totalbill }} in the order.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use @property decorator above your function like that:

```
  @property
  def totalbill(self):
     total = Invoicetracker.objects.all().aggregate( TotalBillAmount = Sum('BillAmount'))
     return total

  @property
  def totalpaid(self):
     total = Invoicetracker.objects.all().aggregate(TotalPaid = Sum('TotalPaid'))
     return total
```

After that, you can call those function inside your template like:

```
{{item.totalbill}}
{{item.totalpaid}}
```

Comment: I am getting the error that the property objects are not callable

Comment: awesome!! saved a day